# Steam error in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, steam

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04. I've installed Steam from a .deb file and the Software app. When I open Steam it starts showing it's updating. Two seconds later it's saying: `Steam Fatal Error: Steam needs to be online to update, confirm your connection and try again`.

Comment: Are you online?

Comment: Is there a reason why you didn't install it from the Ubuntu repos?